# Why are there "skipped" temperature entries in the SCT Temperature History output?

Tags: hard-disk, monitoring, temperature, smartctl

To take a look at the temperature history in on my SSD, I used the `smartctl -l scttemphist` command.  The output says that it is skipping lots of entries.  Why is it doing this?  I don't think that it is because it does not have them saved.

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         10 minutes
Temperature Logging Interval:        10 minutes
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      ?/ ? Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:            ?/ ? Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (0)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
   1    2017-06-26 18:20    30  ***********
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ***********
   5    2017-06-26 19:00    30  ***********
   6    2017-06-26 19:10    31  ************
   7    2017-06-26 19:20    30  ***********
 ...    ..( 60 skipped).    ..  ***********
  68    2017-06-27 05:30    30  ***********
  69    2017-06-27 05:40    29  **********
  70    2017-06-27 05:50    30  ***********
  71    2017-06-27 06:00    30  ***********
  72    2017-06-27 06:10    29  **********
  73    2017-06-27 06:20    30  ***********
  74    2017-06-27 06:30    30  ***********
  75    2017-06-27 06:40    29  **********
  76    2017-06-27 06:50    30  ***********
  77    2017-06-27 07:00    30  ***********
  78    2017-06-27 07:10    29  **********
  79    2017-06-27 07:20    30  ***********
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  ***********
  82    2017-06-27 07:50    30  ***********
  83    2017-06-27 08:00    31  ************
  84    2017-06-27 08:10    30  ***********
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  ***********
  89    2017-06-27 09:00    30  ***********
  90    2017-06-27 09:10    31  ************
  91    2017-06-27 09:20    30  ***********
  92    2017-06-27 09:30    31  ************
 ...    ..( 35 skipped).    ..  ************
   0    2017-06-27 15:30    31  ************
```

Is there a way to get `smartctl` to display the entire history instead of hiding some entries?  I didn't see anything about it in the man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the sources or see [here](https://github.com/jcsp/smartmontools/blob/master/ataprint.cpp#L2229) that `smartctl` is merely optimising the output by removing groups of identical temperatures.  If you want to have all the values, recompile after removing this `while{}` loop at line 2216 (keep the initialisation line).

```
// Find range of identical temperatures
unsigned n1 = n, n2 = n+1, i2 = (i+1) % tmh->cb_size;
while (n2 < tmh->cb_size && tmh->cb[i2] == tmh->cb[i]) {
  n2++; i2 = (i2+1) % tmh->cb_size;
}
```